# How to load images dynamically in to Jasper Reports using image paths stored in database?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am still new to Jasper reports. I'm using "TIBCO Jaspersoft Studio" and trying to build a report.I'm calling the report from a Java application.

In that report I need to add a "profile face image" in to every row dynamically. Those images are stored in my local machine and only the paths to those images are stored in the database.

I need to load images dynamically to that report using those image paths stored in database. Is it possible to do with Jasper reports and Java?
If so please mention how should I proceed?

Thanks

Comment: https://gilbertadjin.wordpress.com/2009/07/01/inserting-images-from-database-into-jasper-reports/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009550/jasper-reports-showing-images-dynamically-depending-on-field-values

Comment: Thank you very much. The second link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009550/jasper-reports-showing-images-dynamically-depending-on-field-values] has a kind of similar way to do it. I was able to succeed. First link [https://gilbertadjin.wordpress.com/2009/07/01/inserting-images-from-database-into-jasper-reports/] refers to load images that are stored in DB in binary format.

Comment: You are welcome , WSo2 +1 :P